# How can I get Python to find local files when running from inside Notepad++?

Tags: python, tkinter, notepad++

I’m using the NppExec plugin to run Python and I’ve used a few variations to get this working, none of which allow the script to find local images.

Here’s an example script:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
#import sys
#import os
#
### get the execution path
#path  =  os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
##
root  =  Tk()
root.title("Game")

frame  =  Frame(root)
frame.pack()

width = 700
height = 400
centre_x = width / 2
centre_y = height / 2

canvas  =  Canvas(frame, bg = "black", width = width, height = height)
canvas.pack()


#background  =  PhotoImage(file = path + "/images/for_loop_breakdown.png")
background  =  PhotoImage(file = "images/for_loop_breakdown.png")
canvas.create_image(centre_x, centre_y, image = background)

#character  =  PhotoImage(file = path + "/images/rectangle.png")
character  =  PhotoImage(file = "images/rectangle.png")
canvas.create_image(centre_x, centre_y, image = character)

root.mainloop()
```

If I uncomment the lines defining the execution path as well as the lines below defining ‘background’ and ‘character’, everything works as expected. But as things are, I get the following error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "images/for_loop_breakdown.png": no such file or directory
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks.

Here are the variations I’ve tried:

```
cmd /K cd "$(FULL_CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" & python "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" & pause & exit

cmd /k "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"

cmd /k c:\path\to\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"

cmd /s /k "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

Comment: I think you have to use `$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)` to get the directory without the current file name, then something along `cmd /K "cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) & python ..."` should work (here the quotes are important!), see https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec/blob/master/docs/NppExec.txt for predefined environment variables

Comment: no, everything in one quote like my example

Comment: Okay, if this is what you mean: ```cmd /K cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" & python "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" & pause & exit``` I've now tried that, too, and it doesn't work. But thanks.

Comment: hmm, I literally mean `cmd /K "cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) & python.exe" `. The point is that everthing in "..." is a parameter to `cmd /K`, otherwise you would do a `cd` but that would not affect the call to `python`

Comment: Just `python -u "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`  works in my Notepad++.

Comment: Thanks, all. I read the nppExec manual and realized I was confusing it with the Run dialog. I now have a working script and adding '-u' to the python command gets me real-time output to the console window. ```NPP_SAVE
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
cmd.exe /c py -u "$(FILE_NAME)"```