# How do I get Notepad++'s nppExec to print to the console as they happen instead of all at once after the script exits?

Tags: python, tkinter, notepad++, nppexec

I've got nppExec set up to execute Python scripts. However, the print statements don't go to the console while the script is executing, only after the script exits. This isn't obvious unless the script opens a GUI.
Is there a way to change nppExec output so it happens "in real time" so to speak?

Comment: Try running the script with `python -u` ("force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered") instead of just `python`.

Comment: You have already found the answer in your another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77908026/how-can-i-get-python-to-find-local-files-when-running-from-inside-notepad), why do you create this question?